# How to verify certificate signature in pyOpenSSL?

Tags: python, pyopenssl

I have two certificates, a `root.crt` that was used to sign `client.crt`.

I want to verify that the `client.crt` was indeed signed by `root.key`.

Using openssl on terminal, it works like this:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile root.crt client.crt  
> client.crt: OK
```

However using pyOpenSSL - following the [documentation](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#x509storecontext-objects) and [this blog post](http://aviadas.com/blog/2015/06/18/verifying-x509-certificate-chain-of-trust-in-python/) - I tried something like this:

```
client_cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, file('client.crt').read())

root_cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, file('root.crt').read())  

store = OpenSSL.crypto.X509Store()  
store.add_cert(root_cert)  

ctx = OpenSSL.crypto.X509StoreContext(store, client_cert)
ctx.verify_certificate()
```

I get this error:

```
    > X509StoreContextError: [2, 1, 'unable to get issuer certificate']
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that my `root.crt` is not really root, but a chain of certificates:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And `OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate` just loads the first one.

The solution is to extract all certificates in the chain file and add them to the `X509Store`.

The code solution looks like this:

```
_PEM_RE = re.compile(b'-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r?.+?\r?-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r?\n?', re.DOTALL)


def parse_chain(chain):
    # returns a list of certificates
    return [c.group() for c in _PEM_RE.finditer(chain)]


client_cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, file('server.crt').read())

store = OpenSSL.crypto.X509Store()
for cert in parse_chain(file('root.crt').read()):
    store.add_cert(OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))

ctx = OpenSSL.crypto.X509StoreContext(store, client_cert)
ctx.verify_certificate()
```

Adapted from https://github.com/hynek/pem/blob/master/src/pem/_core.py#L115

Comment: May I know what is ```cr``` in the ```store.add_cert``` command?

Comment: Updated the code sample, it was a typo. Thanks for noticing!